# Update field on the same table

Tags: ms-access

I have 4 fields, "Name", "Email", "Supervisor's name" and "Supervisor's Email"

How do I do a query to fill up the Supervisor's Email column based on the field Supervisor's name and then find his/her email on the same table ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create the supervisor's email address based on his/her name, there is not need to fill a field with it. Just create it and you have it.

Comment: That's what I want to achieve. Currently the supervisor email is empty. I have to first find out the supervisor name and then look up the email to fill it in. But I am not sure how do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the column `Supervisor's Email` to the `Email` from the `Name` that matches the `Supervisor's Name` then you can do an update by joining the table with itself.

This should do it:

```
update your_table t1
inner join your_table t2 on t2.name = t1.[supervisor's name]
set t1.[supervisor's email] = t2.email
where t1.[supervisor's name] is not null
```